# FBX 6000 file format specification

Tags: binary, deserialization, fbx

I found a FBX 6100 binary file in the Synty-Store War Pack, and neither Assimp (`FBX-DOM unsupported, old format version, supported are only FBX 2011, FBX 2012 and FBX 2013`) nor Blender (`Version 6100 unsupported, must be 7100 or newer`) were able to open it. How can I read them programmatically?

Thank you (answer incoming by myself )

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are an artists, or have very few files, just get the [Autodesk FBX converter](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives). It supports all FBX versions (afaik).
2. If you have access to C++, and easily can use it, and don't have a hard requirement on OpenSource software, or are not exe file size limited, use the [official FBX SDK](https://www.autodesk.com/developer-network/platform-technologies/fbx-converter-archives). It supports all FBX versions (afaik), and should be easy to bind in.
3. If you're in the third camp, and just want to remove all hassle from others and you are developing your own tool or engine, or similar, [like I am](https://github.com/AntonioNoack/RemsEngine/), get ready for what I found out . It's not complete, but it's a description for the structure of the binary data.

FBX 6100 is a quite old version, and is from ~2010, I believe.

The file is encoded in little endian, and starts with the magic `"Kaydara FBX Binary"`. The meaning of the next 5 bytes is unknown to me.
Then the version follows as U32: `6100 (0xd4,0x17)`.
Everything that follows has the same underlying structure, and is an array or tree of nodes:

`U32 endOfBlock, I32 type, I32 dataLength, U8 keyLength, U8[keyLength] key, children or values`.

There are two types of nodes: structural (first or last leaf, type==0), or data (type>0).

- `EndOfBlock` is 0 for each last leaf, and the absolute address of the end of the node data within the file otherwise.
- `DataLength` is 0 iff the node is structural.
- If the node is data, `type` denotes the number of `values` belonging to the `key`.

If the node is structural, until `endOfBlock` is reached, read their child nodes.
Else, read their values:

Each value begins with a marker for their type, and then the data follows immediately.

```
I = 32-bit integer, I32
D = 64-bit float, double, FP64
S = string: I32 length + U8[length] data
R = some uuid, I32 length + U8[length] data
C = character, U8
L = 64-bit integer, I64
```

There might be more, but that is those that I found using HxD.

**And that's it** . The rest is just "usual" FBX, and you can find info about it e.g.,  at [banexdevblog.wordpress.com](https://banexdevblog.wordpress.com/2014/06/23/a-quick-tutorial-about-the-fbx-ascii-format/), and everything else is pretty readable, so it should be much easier to decode for you now :).

If you need help understanding details, or the exact algorithm, you can visit [my implementation within Rem's Engine](https://github.com/AntonioNoack/RemsEngine/blob/master/src/me/anno/mesh/fbx/FBX6000.kt).